# Emacs Widget Library

Tags: keymap, widget

Using this widget:

```
(widget-create 'editable-field :size 4 :format "text1 %v text2")
(widget-setup)
```

I get the following output (where the underscores appear as a fillable grey area)

```
text1 ____ text2
```

In general, when hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> inside an editable field area, the effect is a jump to the next field.
`(widget-setup)` sets the buffer read-only, therefore outside the editable area, hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> gives `widget-before-change: Text is read-only: "Attempt to change text outside editable field"`.

However, if I place the cursor immediately before `text2`, hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> inserts an undesired newline, while that should be a read-only area.

Why is a newline added despite that is a read-only area?
How can I prevent the newline insertion?

Comment: Note, that the [`point` is the insertion positions **between** character positions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Point.html). The rectangular cursor is a bit misleading in that regard. The relevant part of the cursor is its left edge which is actually better represented by the vertical bar you get when you customize [`cursor-type`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Cursor-Display.html#Cursor-Display) to `bar`. Difficult to spot -- not the default. Your problem does not occur immediately before `text2` but immediately behind the widget field.

Comment: Note that you can insert a linebreak anywhere in the widget field -- not by `RET` but by `C-q C-j` (which corresponds more or less to a literal `RET`). `RET` does not insert a linebreak in the widget field since it is bound to `widget-field-activate` in the `widget-field-keymap` which is active in the widget field.

Comment: @Drew Those are really comments. The answer is quite more complicated. Widgets have their own treatment of overlays. See `widget-before-change`, `widget-after-change`, and the comment about not subtracting 1 if `local-map` is working at the end of the overlay in `widget-field-end`.

Comment: @Drew I dug that deep when I got puzzled about the active keymap at the insertion end of the overlay which is one more than the last character position in the overlay. The overlay keymap shouldn't be active there but it magically is.

Comment: The only solution I could come up with is hacky: Do what they do when a field ends in a newline -- add a 'field` property with value `boundary` and the widget as value for `real-field` to the space: `(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*test*")
  (setq wid (widget-create 'editable-field :size 4 :format "text1 %v"))
  (widget-create 'editable-field :size 0 :format (concat (propertize " " 'field 'boundary 'real-field wid) "text2"))
  (widget-setup))`

Comment: @Tobias: For the record: `M-x customize`. Hit enter just before the search button (immediately behind the widget field) and you have again this nasty behaviour. Is it the way it should be or is it a bug?

Comment: You asked whether the behavior is a bug. I am not in the position to decide that. Just try and report it as an emacs bug to find out: [`M-x report-emacs-bug`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Reporting-bugs.html).

Comment: @Tobias: BTW, I posted a more general workaround. Maybe you want to have a look and possibly spot something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**Analysis of the problem**

Looking at `wid-edit.el`, the only call to `widget-field-activate` happens inside `widget-field-keymap`:

```
(defvar widget-field-keymap
  (let ((map (copy-keymap widget-keymap)))
    ...
    (define-key map "\C-m" 'widget-field-activate)
    ...
```

I cannot find the function used elsewhere, therefore  the `widget-field-activate` action can *only* be triggered when `widget-field-keymap` is active and when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed. Since this keymap is associated to editable fields, it means one should be *inside a field and hit* <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

There is however a "dead" spot on the right field boundary  where an anomalous behaviour happens:

1. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> triggers `widget-field-activate`, which would imply you are inside the field.
2. However, using a Edebug, shows that this point is outside a field. In fact,

   ```
   (get-char-property (point) 'field)
   ```

   returns `nil`, rather than the field properties.

The function `widget-field-keymap` controls for this and: if  <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed inside the field, activates the field; if  <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed outside, executes the standard `widget-global-map` binding for RET, which is `(newline)`:

```
(defun widget-field-activate (pos &optional event)
  "Invoke the editable field at point."
  (interactive "@d")
  (let ((field (widget-field-at pos)))    ; <- the func checks if we are in a field
    (if field
    (widget-apply-action field event)
      (call-interactively                 ; <- if not, lookup-key returns newline 
       (lookup-key widget-global-map (this-command-keys))))))
```

Calling the newline causes the bizarre result of *visually breaking* the field, spanning it over two lines.
Instead, the function should do nothing if the activation cannot proceed or perhaps return the usual read-only warning. Hence, the following

**General workaround**

```
(defun widget-field-activate (pos &optional event)
(interactive "@d")
  (let ((field (widget-field-at pos)))
    (if field
    (widget-apply-action field event)
      (message "Text is read-only: \"Attempt to change text outside editable field\""))))
```

I don't know if this version fixes a bug, but I haven't found any side effect  and that produces a more desirable behaviour.

Comment: I can't find any bug report mentioning `widget-field-activate`.  As per the comments, this should be reported with `M-x report-emacs-bug` for discussion -- especially if you believe you may have a patch which fixes it.

Comment: @phils: My Emacs is not configured to send emails and emails sent directly to bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org do not show on gnu.emacs.bug newsgroup. In case your Emacs is enabled, I'll be glad if you could submit this post.